# Equality in Agda - irrelevant arguments

Tags: equality, agda, lifting

I have a dependant type that consists of a value plus some proofs about its properties. Naturally I would like my notion of equality over this type to be equivalent to equality over the value component. This is all fine except that I run into problems when proving properties of lifted notions of this equality (for example equality over lists of this type).

For example:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Binary.List.Pointwise renaming (Rel to ListRel) hiding (refl)

module Test where

    _≈_ : Rel (ℕ × ℕ) _
    (a₁ , _) ≈ (a₂ , _) = a₁ ≡ a₂

    ≈-sym : Symmetric _≈_
    ≈-sym refl = refl

    ≋-sym : Symmetric (ListRel _≈_)
    ≋-sym = symmetric ≈-sym
```

In the last line Agda complains that it can't solve for the second projections out of the pairs. Interestingly changing the last line to the following eta-equivalent expression means that it can solve them:

```
    ≋-sym = symmetric (λ {x} {y} → ≈-sym {x} {y})
```

Now naturally I know that sometimes Agda can't solve for all the implicit arguments and needs a bit of extra help but I don't understand what new information I'm providing it by doing this...

I'm doing a lot of lifting of equality and I'd rather avoid adding these ugly eta expansions everywhere in my code. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to allow something similar to the original code to pass?

I have looked into [irrelevance](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Irrelevance) but the second projection is used elsewhere, even if it is computationally irrelevant for equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing, but I think the problem is that the order of implicit arguments doesn't matter for (a part of) unification. Consider

```
flipped : (({n m : ℕ} -> n ≡ m) -> ℕ) -> ({m n : ℕ} -> n ≡ m) -> ℕ
flipped k f = k f
```

Here `k` receives something of type `{n m : ℕ} -> n ≡ m` and `f` is of type `{m n : ℕ} -> n ≡ m` (`m` comes before `n`), but Agda happily unifies these two expressions, since each implicit argument becomes a metavariable during elaboration and metas are not ordered by when they was introduced — they are ordered by how they was instantiated (e.g. you can't instantiate `α` to `β -> β` and then `β` to `α` as it would result in `α ≡ α -> α` and handling such loops (called equirecursive types) is an unsound nightmare). So when you write

```
 ≋-sym = symmetric ≈-sym
```

Agda is confused, because it could mean any of

```
 ≋-sym = symmetric (λ {x} {y} → ≈-sym {x} {y})
 ≋-sym = symmetric (λ {x} {y} → ≈-sym {y} {x})
```

(well, not quite, because the second expression is ill-typed, but Agda doesn't backtrack and can't solve such problems therefore)

This is different from the `flipped` example, because `flipped` explicitly specifies how `n` and `m` are used, so unification of

```
{n1 m1 : ℕ} -> n1 ≡ m1
{m2 n2 : ℕ} -> n2 ≡ m2
```

results in `n1 ≡ n2` and `m1 ≡ m2` and hence the problem is solved. If you drop this specification

```
unsolved : (({n m : ℕ} -> ℕ) -> ℕ) -> ({m n : ℕ} -> ℕ) -> ℕ
unsolved k f = k f
```

you'll get unsolved metas back.

The exact problem with your definition is that only the first projections of pairs are mentioned in the RHS of `_≈_`, so Agda doesn't know how to unify the second projections. Here is a workaround:

```
record Sing {α} {A : Set α} (x : A) : Set where

module Test where

    _≈_ : Rel (ℕ × ℕ) _
    (a₁ , b₁) ≈ (a₂ , b₂) = a₁ ≡ a₂ × Sing (b₁ , b₂)

    ≈-sym : Symmetric _≈_
    ≈-sym (refl , _) = (refl , _)

    ≋-sym : Symmetric (ListRel _≈_)
    ≋-sym = symmetric ≈-sym
```

`Sing` is a dummy record that have only one inhabitant that can be inferred automatically. But `Sing` allows to mention `b₁` and `b₂` in the RHS of `_≈_` in an inference-friendly way, which makes those metas in `≋-sym` solvable.

Though, it seems that `(a₁ , b₁) ≈ (a₂ , b₂) = a₁ ≡ a₂ × Sing b₁` already gives Agda enough hints how to solve metas in `≋-sym`.

You can also define a pattern synonym to make the code slightly nicer:

```
pattern refl₁ = (refl , _)

≈-sym : Symmetric _≈_
≈-sym refl₁ = refl₁
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, and the suggested solution of how to get around it! However, although the ordering of variables bit makes sense, I'm not so sure it's the underlying cause of the problem. For instance you get the same problem if you try and prove reflexivity instead of symmetry `≋-refl = pw-refl ≈-refl ` which doesn't have multiple implicit arguments to reorder.

Comment: @user2667523, `≋-refl` is not a counterexample, since Agda has eta rules for records and `{p : A × B} -> ...` is the same thing as `{x : A} {y : B} -> ...`. However you're right: `unsolved : (({n : ℕ} -> ℕ) -> ℕ) -> ({n : ℕ} -> ℕ) -> ℕ; unsolved k f = k f` does result in unsolved metas. So it seems that implicit arguments get unified only during the process of explicit arguments unification.